# Using consumable items with In-App Purchase for permanent items

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, iphone-sdk-3.1

For my upcoming iPhone application I'd like to offer In-App purchases of expansion content (things like additional unit types), but I'd like to offer them in a booster-style format, i.e., you buy a booster pack and get X new unit types out of Y total units.  Units can stack and are useful in duplicate, so you can get some of the same units you already have.  I have a few questions about this model:

- Will this rub against Apple's "Be clear about what's included in the item"?  I can be clear that you are receiving a random set of units and that you may receive duplicates according to a specific distribution mix, but I'm still not sure about this one.
- While these booster pack-style purchases will be consumable for the sole reason that I want to allow the user to repeat them, the items they receive are not truly 'consumable'.  I'm thinking I can store the user's purchases on my server to allow them to always access and backup their purchased content, but again, I'm not sure if this will get the app rejected or not.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here after forever; I found the application Urban Rivals which apparently employs this approach successfully.